# Polymer .render() for template repeat not updating correctly. (Missing Array values)

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer-1.0

So here is a quick run down. I call .render() on my template repeat and it updates the list but the new items that are in the array are blank.

So for the long explanation....

Anytime I modify "pizza" I call a function that does the following (through observer):

```
  this.$.repeatModToppings.render();
  this.$.repeatModGarnish.render();
  this.$.repeatModSauce.render();
  this.$.repeatModCuts.render();
  console.log(this.pizza);
```

Here are the contents of the first call (original array):

[image]

This is what the template repeat shows:

[image]

After the array updates it shows this:

[image]

However... here is what the template repeat is showing after the .render() is called on it:

[image]

The "item.name" is displaying as a blank. Any ideas as to what might be happening?

**EDIT:**
Here is some additional code.

My template repeat:

```
<div class="pizza-mod-body-right">
    <template id="repeatModToppings" is="dom-repeat" items="{{pizza.TOPPINGS}}" as="topping">
        <div class="mod-text-block">
            0-{{topping.name}}
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

As you can see this is pretty basic. However, I am still getting the issue with it thinking that this array has some sort of blank values for their names :(

Comment: Did you get this problem solved? - I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no. What I did to get around this issue was I made my own version of the template repeat and removed the polymer version and got it to work. This could also be because one of your elements is using the same named variable as this element. Look into that as well.